# Why do I see this error when trying to open the control designer in visual studio and how do I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, controls, visual-studio-2019

Why do I see this error when trying to open the control designer in visual studio 2019 and how do I fix it?

(Winforms)

[image]

The error switches sometimes when I try to open the designer:

[image]

I tried reinstalling Visual Studio but I am still getting this.

CustomContol1.cs
Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DBControls
{
    public partial class CustomControl1 : Control
    {
        public CustomControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

CustomContol1.Designer.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DBControls
{
    public partial class CustomControl1 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: click on `Show Call Stack` and show us what it reads there

Comment: I edited the original post with more info.

Comment: I guess you have already restarted VS ? We need to see the code of this file, with the information we have we can only guess

Comment: Not only restarted, but completely uninstalled and reinstalled VS

Comment: Edited again with added code. It's just what is generated.

Comment: This is the default behavior: you're inheriting from Control, using the standard Custom Control Template. You don't have a default Designer, you have to provide your own cooked Designer or build one inheriting from one of the existing designers. -- If you just don't want to show the message in the second Window, decorate the class with  `[DesignerCategory("Control")]` or `[DesignerCategory("code")]` -- To build reusable Controls / UserControls, add them to a class Library that targets AnyCPU. -- .Net Framework and .Net components are not compatible.

Comment: If you decide to provide your own Designer, you have to create a custom [IRootDesigner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.irootdesigner) first.

Answer (score 1):

you do not have a usercontrol, but you have inherited from `Control`.
This means there is nothing to design, and therefor the designer crashes

If you wish to build a usercontrol that you can edit in the designer, than you need to inherit from `UserControl` instead.
I am not sure if you can just edit this file and get it working, normally you have to use create new project and then choose customcontrol to do this.

here is an example on how to choose a project for this

[image]

this will create a dll that you can use in other project, in those projects you will have to click right mouse in the `Toolbox` and then `choose items`.
In the next screen you need to browse to the dll you created here and select it.
From then on all controls in that dll will be available in that project to drag onto forms

Comment: I didn't write any of the code. It was all generated by VS after selecting CustomControl from the VS Add new item dialog.

Comment: You probably choose something else then you expected, for a customcontrol that can be edited in the designer you need to inherit from UserControl

Comment: I need to be able to make the control I am trying to make available in the toolbox for other projects and developers. So, I presume this would have to be in the form of a DLL? It's not just to be in this one project.

Comment: This is to target .Net 5. When I tried this selecting the Windows Forms Control (Library .Net Framework), it adds the control but VS says it's not available as the forms designer is incompatible?